# Arrows segmentations in an image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I need a way to segment each arrow alone. I tried OpenCv findContours but it broke it or add it to multiple shapes and arrows as the share the boundaries of shapes. I tried OpenCV connected components but this arrows almost in some graph connected all of it. Plus having trouble as the **boundaries almost have the same color as the arrow**. And in these kind of images each **arrow contains different colors**. Any opinion about this problem.

[image: A sample of the images I have o deal with]

This is a sample diagram. I have to deal with harder diagrams like this.
[image: More complex diagram]

Comment: could you share your expected output given this input ? do you want to identify start/center/end points of arrows (consequently you have a list of (start_pt, end_pt) representation of arrows); or do you want to just segment them without need of contextual information?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to find the start and end of each arrow. But if I can get array of each arrow individually I can do the rest. If this array has another shapes within I can build a classifier for it. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Do you want to detect both arrows: black and white?

Comment: If I can it would be great. If I can't and there is a solution color based ok. But this low res images has variances in the intensity of black in this images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, work with new picture.
1. Binarization the arrows (and shapes):

```
cv::Mat imgCl = cv::imread("62uoU.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Mat img;
cv::cvtColor(imgCl, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::Mat mask1;
cv::threshold(img, mask1, 30, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

cv::Mat mask2;
cv::threshold(img, mask2, 120, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

cv::Mat diff;
cv::absdiff(mask1, mask2, diff);

cv::imshow("diff1", diff);
```

Result 1:

[image: Arrows binarization]

2. Remove rectangle shapes:

   cv::Rect objRect(0, 0, diff.cols, diff.rows);
       cv::Size minSize(objRect.width / 100, objRect.height / 100);

   ```
   cv::Mat bin = cv::Mat(diff, objRect).clone();

   for (;;)
   {
       cv::Rect cutRect;
       if (!PosRefinement(bin, cutRect, 0.9f, minSize))
       {
           break;
       }
       cv::rectangle(bin, cutRect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::FILLED);
       cv::rectangle(diff, cutRect, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), cv::FILLED);

       objRect.x += cutRect.x;
       objRect.y += cutRect.y;
       objRect.width = cutRect.width;
       objRect.height = cutRect.height;
   }

   cv::imshow("diff", diff);
   ```

Result 2:

[image: Only arrows]

3. Find lines:

   ```
   std::vector<cv::Vec4i> linesP;
   cv::HoughLinesP(diff, linesP, 1, CV_PI / 180, 20, 10, 5);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < linesP.size(); i++)
   {
       cv::Vec4i l = linesP[i];
       cv::line(imgCl, cv::Point(l[0], l[1]), cv::Point(l[2], l[3]), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, cv::LINE_AA);
   }
   cv::imshow("img", imgCl);
   ```

Result 3:

[image: Draw lines]

Black arrows was founded. It can to improve this solution: find and delete text areas from image (tesseract or cv::text::ERFilter). And add a little morphology for draw arrow tips with Hough lines.

P.S. Utility function:

```
bool PosRefinement(
    cv::Mat bin,
    cv::Rect& cutRect,
    double kThreshold,
    cv::Size minSize
    )
{
    const double areaThreshold = 100;
    const int radius = 5;
    const int maxIters = 100;

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(bin, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point());

    size_t bestCont = contours.size();
    double maxArea = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
        if (area > maxArea)
        {
            maxArea = area;
            bestCont = i;
        }
    }
    if (maxArea < areaThreshold)
    {
        return false;
    }

    cv::Moments m = cv::moments(contours[bestCont]);
    cv::Point mc(cvRound(m.m10 / m.m00), cvRound(m.m01 / m.m00));

    cv::Rect currRect(mc.x - radius / 2, mc.y - radius / 2, radius, radius);

    auto Clamp = [](int v, int hi) -> bool
    {
        if (v < 0)
        {
            v = 0;
            return true;
        }
        else if (hi && v > hi - 1)
        {
            v = hi - 1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    auto RectClamp = [&](cv::Rect& r, int w, int h) -> bool
    {
        return Clamp(r.x, w) || Clamp(r.x + r.width, w) || Clamp(r.y, h) || Clamp(r.y + r.height, h);
    };

    int stepL = radius / 2;
    int stepR = radius / 2;
    int stepT = radius / 2;
    int stepB = radius / 2;

    double k = 0;

    struct State
    {
        double k = 0;
        int stepL = 0;
        int stepR = 0;
        int stepT = 0;
        int stepB = 0;
        cv::Rect currRect;

        State() = default;
        State(double k_, int stepL_, int stepR_, int stepT_, int stepB_, cv::Rect currRect_)
            :
              k(k_),
              stepL(stepL_),
              stepR(stepR_),
              stepT(stepT_),
              stepB(stepB_),
              currRect(currRect_)
        {
        }
        bool operator==(const State& st) const
        {
            return (st.k == k) && (st.stepL == stepL) && (st.stepR == stepR) && (st.stepT == stepT) && (st.stepB == stepB) && (st.currRect == currRect);
        }
    };
    const size_t statesCount = 2;
    State prevStates[statesCount];
    size_t stateInd = 0;

    for (int it = 0; it < maxIters; ++it)
    {
        cv::Rect rleft(currRect.x - stepL, currRect.y, currRect.width + stepL, currRect.height);
        cv::Rect rright(currRect.x, currRect.y, currRect.width + stepR, currRect.height);
        cv::Rect rtop(currRect.x, currRect.y - stepT, currRect.width, currRect.height + stepT);
        cv::Rect rbottom(currRect.x, currRect.y, currRect.width, currRect.height + stepB);

        double kleft = 0;
        double kright = 0;
        double ktop = 0;
        double kbottom = 0;

        if (!RectClamp(rleft, bin.cols, bin.rows))
        {
            cv::Rect rstep(currRect.x - stepL, currRect.y, stepL, currRect.height);
            if (cv::sum(bin(rstep))[0] / (255.0 * rstep.area()) > kThreshold / 2)
            {
                kleft = cv::sum(bin(rleft))[0] / (255.0 * rleft.area());
            }
        }
        if (!RectClamp(rright, bin.cols, bin.rows))
        {
            cv::Rect rstep(currRect.x + currRect.width, currRect.y, stepR, currRect.height);
            if (cv::sum(bin(rstep))[0] / (255.0 * rstep.area()) > kThreshold / 2)
            {
                kright = cv::sum(bin(rright))[0] / (255.0 * rright.area());
            }
        }
        if (!RectClamp(rtop, bin.cols, bin.rows))
        {
            cv::Rect rstep(currRect.x, currRect.y - stepT, currRect.width, stepT);
            if (cv::sum(bin(rstep))[0] / (255.0 * rstep.area()) > kThreshold / 2)
            {
                ktop = cv::sum(bin(rtop))[0] / (255.0 * rtop.area());
            }
        }
        if (!RectClamp(rbottom, bin.cols, bin.rows))
        {
            cv::Rect rstep(currRect.x, currRect.y + currRect.height, currRect.width, stepB);
            if (cv::sum(bin(rstep))[0] / (255.0 * rstep.area()) > kThreshold / 2)
            {
                kbottom = cv::sum(bin(rbottom))[0] / (255.0 * rbottom.area());
            }
        }

        bool wasEnlargeX = false;
        if (kleft > kThreshold)
        {
            currRect.x -= stepL;
            currRect.width += stepL;
            wasEnlargeX = true;

            if (kleft > k)
            {
                ++stepL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (stepL > 1)
            {
                --stepL;
            }
            currRect.x += 1;
            currRect.width -= 1;
        }
        if (kright > kThreshold)
        {
            currRect.width += stepR;
            wasEnlargeX = true;

            if (kright > k)
            {
                ++stepR;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (stepR > 1)
            {
                --stepR;
            }
            currRect.width -= 1;
        }

        bool wasEnlargeY = false;
        if (ktop > kThreshold)
        {
            currRect.y -= stepT;
            currRect.height += stepT;
            wasEnlargeY = true;

            if (ktop > k)
            {
                ++stepT;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (stepT > 1)
            {
                --stepT;
            }
            currRect.y += 1;
            currRect.height -= 1;
        }
        if (kbottom > kThreshold)
        {
            currRect.height += stepB;
            wasEnlargeY = true;

            if (kbottom > k)
            {
                ++stepB;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (stepB > 1)
            {
                --stepB;
            }
            currRect.height -= 1;
        }

        k = cv::sum(bin(currRect))[0] / (255.0 * currRect.area());

        State currState(k, stepL, stepR, stepT, stepB, currRect);

        bool repState = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < statesCount; ++i)
        {
            if (prevStates[i] == currState)
            {
                repState = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (repState)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            prevStates[stateInd] = currState;
            stateInd = (stateInd + 1 < statesCount) ? (stateInd + 1) : 0;
        }

        if (k < kThreshold && (stepL + stepR + stepT + stepB == 4) && !wasEnlargeX && !wasEnlargeY)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cutRect.x = std::max(0, currRect.x - 1);
    cutRect.width = currRect.width + 2;
    cutRect.y = std::max(0, currRect.y - 1);
    cutRect.height = currRect.height + 2;

    return (cutRect.width >= minSize.width) && (cutRect.height >= minSize.height);
}
```

Comment: Please just adjust the code in part 2 and 3 code is not formatted. So if someone else wants to read it. Great job.

Answer (score 1):

For your example it might be simple. The picture (png) has 4 channels and 4th channel is transparent mask. It can work only with transparent channel and filter arrows with moments:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("voXFs.png", cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
std::cout << "imsize = " << img.size() << ", chans = " << img.channels() << std::endl;
cv::imshow("img", img);

std::vector<cv::Mat> chans;
cv::split(img, chans);

cv::imshow("transp", chans.back());

cv::Mat mask;
cv::threshold(chans.back(), mask, 50, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(mask, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cv::Mat draw;
cv::cvtColor(mask, draw, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
{
    double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
    double len = cv::arcLength(contours[i], false);
    double k = len / area;

    if (area > 10 && len > 60 && k > 2)
    {
        std::cout << "area = " << area << ", len = " << len << ", k = " << k << std::endl;
        cv::drawContours(draw, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
    }
}

cv::imshow("mask", mask);
cv::imshow("draw", draw);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

[image: Result:]

But for more robust result:

1. Find and delete text areas from image (tesseract or cv::text::ERFilter).
2. Erode mask, find all shapes by contours, draw and dilate they. Bitwise and operation for mask and result.
3. The end!

Comment: This failed really bad on my first test case.  It can be a "jpg" file with no 4 channels. Plus it can be inside another object. I will update a post with a real image. But thanks for your time and try.